# Jruby-Convert RubyString to Java Char

Tags: jruby

Below is the code i am using to Convert from RubyString to Java Char.. Could you please suggest me better way where Jruby (automatically handles these kind of Type Error or some code in jruby to convert)

```
ruby_string="Raj"

java.lang.String.new(col_value)
col_value=str_obj.charAt(0)
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the first character of ruby_string? And what's the broader purpose of what you're trying to do?

Comment: No.. i was trying to convert above ruby_string(ruby_string) to Java Character to call java method which accepts java char as argument

Answer (score 7):

First, JRuby behaves a little differently depending on whether you run it in 1.8 mode or 1.9 mode. With JRuby 1.7.0 and up, 1.9 is the default; with others, 1.8 is the default. To change the default, you pass either `--1.8` or `--1.9` to `jruby` on the command line.

In 1.8 mode, certain operations on strings, like getting the character at a single index, return numbers (`Fixnum`s), whereas in 1.9 mode they always return strings. JRuby converts automatically between Ruby `Fixnum`s between 0 and 65535 and Java `char`s, so you can pass a 1.8-mode "character" value directly to a Java method that accepts a character; e.g.

```
str = 'foo'
java_obj.methodThatTakesAChar(str[0])
```

In 1.9 mode, since `str[0]` is a single-character string, you have to convert its character to a number. You do this with the `ord` instance method:

```
str = 'foo'
java_obj.methodThatTakesAChar(str[0].ord)
```

I hope that helps.